# Pushing to custom stack class freezing .exe

Tags: c++, class, stack

I'm using a stack class, however every time I push something to the stack, the executable freezes and stops working once the line of code pushing is reached.

Could I please get some help on as to why?

My stack.h:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include <cassert>

namespace standard
{
    class Stack
    {
    public:
        static const int CAPACITY = 30;
        void stack() {used=0;};
        void push (const char entry);
        void pop();
        bool empty() const;
        int size() const;
        char top() const;
    private:
        char data[CAPACITY];
        int used;
    };
}

#endif
```

My stack.cpp:

```
#include "stack.h"

namespace standard
{
    void Stack::push(const char entry)
    {
        assert(size() < CAPACITY);
        data[used] = entry;
        ++used;
    }

    void Stack::pop()
    {
        assert(!empty());
        --used;
    }

    char Stack::top() const
    {
        assert(!empty());
        return data[used-1];
    }

    int Stack::size() const
    {
        return used;
    }

    bool Stack::empty() const
    {
        if (size() == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

My calc.cpp:

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace standard;

    void main()
    {
        Stack myStack;
        ifstream input;
        input.open("tests.txt");
        if (input.fail())
        {
            cerr << "Could not open input file." << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        char i;
        input >> i;
        cout << i;
        myStack.push(i);  // This is where things go wrong.
        cin.get();
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not initializing `used`, you have something that may look like a constructor here but it is not:

```
void stack() {used=0;};
```

this is what it should look like:

```
Stack() { used=0;};
```

So without a constructor `used` is going to be some indeterminate value and will probably end up with you attempting to access `data` way out of bounds. Also `main` should always return `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void stack() {used=0;};
```

should this be capitalised? & remove the void!

```
Stack myStack;
```

should this be

```
Stack myStack = new Stack();
```

if you don't initialise it, the variable `myStack` will be a "null pointer".

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrote this function wrong:

```
void stack() {used=0;};
                     //^^extra ; here
```

should be

```
Stack() {used = 0;}
//^^Note that constructor has no return type
```

You have never really used the `stack` member function which return void. This results in the fact that `used` was never initialized. You probably mean the constructor of `Stack`. Meanwhile, you should use constructor initialization list:

```
Stack(): used(0) {}
```